# See all super classes in Java

Tags: java, plugins, ide, eclipse-plugin, superclass

Say you have a class A and a class B extends A and a class C extends B.

Is there any IDE or any sort of plug-in for any idea, where in the file C.Java, on line

```
Class C extends B
```

I can see something like ( and Class A ) for example like a tooltip or like a comment under the line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Eclipse, you can position the caret on the type name press F4 to see the type hierarchy. This will show the type path from `Object` to the indicated type name and all subtypes of that name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ctrl-T` to see quick class hierarchy popup. And while it is open, hitting `Ctrl-T` again will show you a reversed class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open *Class hierarchy* pop-up. Another useful shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> which will display UML diagram of the class in question.